# Find references to string/symbol/method

Tags: smalltalk

This relates to the Dolphin variant of Smalltalk.

I'm digging around in the image to try and figure this out but haven't 
find the correct method invocation yet and I'm hoping someone might be 
able to help shortcut this process.  What I'm trying to do is to find 
all methods (either within the entire system or, preferably, just 
within a single class) which refer to a given string, symbol, or 
method.  I've found the #references family of methods in 
SmalltalkSystem but have not had luck figuring out how to get them to 
give back something resembling what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The programmatic way, here we go

```
SmalltalkSystem current browseContainingText: 'Dolphin'.
```

Comment: Thanks, both to Lukas and Adrian.  These were excellent suggestions, but the code that I needed to scan was in a BlockClosure, and the eventual solution was something like  
  
aBlock method sendsMessage: aSymbol  
  
and  
  
aBlock method refersToLiteral: aString  
  
Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Dolphin at hand, but the following code should work in all Smalltalk with the refactoring engine (this includes Dolphin):

```
result := BrowserEnvironment new matches: 'Dolphin'.
```

Then you can iterate over the results like this:

```
result classesAndSelectorsDo: [ :class :selector | ... ].
```